# How to extract the price with importxml google sheets xpath

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

Good morning,

I can't extract the price on this page with the importxml function:
https://www.t-collector.com/reine?prop%5Bcolor%5D=black&product=26&side=front

I need it to update my google merchant files.
I've tried different formulas like:

```
=importxml(G2;"//span[@itemprop='price']")
=importxml(G2;"//b[@itemprop='price']/@content")
=importxml(G2;"//b[@itemprop='price'][1]/@content")
=importxml(G2;"//meta[@itemprop='price'][1]/@content")
=importxml("G2";"//span[@itemprop='price']")
```

but nothing works

Thanks
Sincerely

Comment: Please post a sample sheet with 3 different formulas you have tried.

Comment: Good morning, sir, 
I've tried different formulas like: 

=importxml(G2;"//span[@itemprop='price']")

=importxml(G2;"//b[@itemprop='price']/@content")

=importxml(G2;"//b[@itemprop='price'][1]/@content")

=importxml(G2;"//meta[@itemprop='price'][1]/@content")

=importxml("G2";"//span[@itemprop='price']")

but nothing works.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website uses dynamic rendering. Selenium would be required here. But we can try with GoogleSheets. We use a custom script to load directly the JSON data.

The script to import JSON data with GoogleSheets (credits to Paul Gambill) : https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164

And the data :

```
https://www.t-collector.com/campaigns/C-PGE7F?format=json&store=tcollectorofficiel
```

We use SQL-like formulas to keep only the price. Result :

[image: TShirt]

EDIT : Solution with IMPORTXML :

You can use the following formula (tested with 5 shirts) :

```
=IMPORTXML(A2;"substring-after(substring-before((//script)[6],'"",""category""'),',""price"":""')")
```

Output :
[image: TShirtsv2]

EDIT 2 : Fix to extract the default displayed price in euros :

```
=IMPORTXML(A2;"substring-after(substring-before(//script[starts-with(.,'var campaignObj')],'"",""gbp""'),'""eur"":""')")
```

Output :

[image: FixTS]

EDIT 3 : To ignore on sale prices, we can use the following one liner :

```
=SI(IMPORTXML(A2;"substring(substring-after(//script[starts-with(.,'var campaignObj')],'""compare_at_prices"":{""eur"":""'),1,1)")=0;IMPORTXML(A2;"substring-after(substring-before(//script[starts-with(.,'var campaignObj')],'"",""gbp""'),'""eur"":""')");IMPORTXML(A2;"substring-before(substring-after(//script[starts-with(.,'var campaignObj')],'""compare_at_prices"":{""eur"":""'),'""')"))
```

Output :

[image: CorrectionOnSale]

Comment: Hello and thank you very much. 

So it's impossible to do it with the IMPORTXML function? 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Impossible ?... We can try. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Hey, guys, 
You're great! 

However on this example here: 
https://www.t-collector.com/vatfaireencorner-v1?prop%5Bcolor%5D=black&product=21&side=front

I find 19.95€ and not 29.95€, it doesn't take the default product price displayed, but the price of another variant. 

Thank you for your precious help and sorry for the mistakes I use a translator, I am French. 

Kind regards

Comment: I found the right one in the source code here: 
"ecommtz_total_value": "29.95", "purchase"

But I don't know how to change your formula.

Comment: It works like this: 
=IMPORTXML(G2; "substring-after(substring-before((//script)[6],'"",""purchase""'),',""ecommtz_total_value"":"""')")

Now the problem is that the extracted value is in USD, because I guess it's the Google bot that triggers the display in USD and not in EUR as I wish .

Comment: OK. I've updated my answer with a fix. Side note : your proposed formula contains a typo. Should have been `=IMPORTXML(A2;"substring-after(substring-before((//script)[6],'"",""purchase""'),',""ecommtz_total_value"":""')")` Mark my answer as accepted if it fulfill your expectations. Et bonne continuation de confinement.;)

Comment: It's perfect, it works, thank you very much.
I close the question, thank you and good continuation to you.

Comment: Hello, friend, 

I'm coming back to you because I'm having a problem with discounted rates like this: 
https://www.t-collector.com/alcoolocation?prop%5Bcolor%5D=black&product=32&side=front

The previous code extracted 29.95€ while I would like 19.95€, do you have a solution to extract this 19.95€ please? 

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hmm. The price seems correctly extracted : https://framapic.org/Esj4P7QnwA45/cYZnbO3Qd1WJ.PNG

Comment: Excuse me, I made a mistake, I just wanted to get the base price, in the example, how to extract the 29.95€? 

Thanks to you